# In Prolog, how can I check for N of elements in list A in list B?

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have these two lists =

```
fruits([banana, apple, mangoes, pears]).
foodILike([hamburgers, banana, shakes, fries]).
```

I want to write a prolog predicate that will return true as soon as it sees 1 items in the foodsILike list in the fruits list. How can I go about doing so?

Comment: Do you need to check for `N` items overlapping or just one?  Also, is this homework?

Comment: Not really HW - I'm more interested in how to do something in Prolog that involves a more complicated form of recursion.

Answer (score 3):

First, for the plain answer:

```
fruitsILike(F) :-
  fruits(Fs)
  member(F, Fs),
  foodILike(Ls),
  member(F, Ls).
```

You could avoid the membership check by flattening the fruits and foods lists:

```
fruit(banana).
fruit(apple).
...
foodILike(hamburger).
foodILike(banana).
...
fruitsILike(F) :-
  fruit(F),
  foodILike(F).
```

That said, you seem to try and solve problems in Prolog using imperative idioms, and that won't work.  First, predicates do not return anything.  When calling a predicate, Prolog unifies its arguments with valid values according to the facts and rules in the program.  Therefore, the "returned value" are the assignments to unbound variables.  Second, Prolog does not do something "as soon as".  It iterates over all possible solutions.  You get the first solution, then the second solution, and so on.

Comment: +1. I suggest two improvements to the first version: 1. put both calls to `member` at the end, so Prolog won't need to backtrack over the call to `foodILike`, and 2. use a `memberchk` instead of the second call to `member`.

Comment: @larsmans: I agree with your improvements, but the second version is the better one anyway.  IHMO it is bad practice to put lists in facts; using multi-clause predicates is more natural.

Comment: @Bobby: true, but the OP's original question was about the intersection of two lists.

Answer (score 1):

`member` can 1) individually generate all the members of a given list and/or 2) give a yes/no answer as to whether a particular element is in a particular list. I believe you want to use the first form on `fruits` to generate each of the elements of `fruit`, and the second form on `foodILike` to see if any of those is present.

Comment: This is news to me - how can I tell if member gives me a yes or no answer? Something like if(member) then (do something). Or is the whole if-statement thing not allowed in prolog?

Comment: Hmm...it's been a long time since I wrote any Prolog, so bear with me. You don't (normally anyway) write something like an if-statement -- you just have a rule that will only succeed if some element of X is also an element of Y. You can get a yes/no (or, equivalently, true/false) answer if you enter the same query at the Prolog command prompt, so something like `? member(A, [A, B, C])` will give 'yes' but `? member(A, [B, C])` will give 'no'. In a larger expression, it'll just fail to unify, so the expression as a whole fails.

Comment: @Waffles: you can do if-then-else with (assuming Little Bobby Tables' answer) `fruitsILike(F) -> write(F) ; write('I do not like fruit').` http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node89.html#sec.l10.if.then.else